# Is network security / encryption provided by default in docker swarm mode?

Tags: ssl, docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

In [this document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/overlay-security-model/) it says that:

> Overlay networking for Docker Engine swarm mode comes secure out of the box.  You can also encrypt data exchanged between containers on different nodes on the overlay network. To enable encryption, when you create an overlay network pass the --opt encrypted flag:

```
> $ docker network create --opt encrypted --driver overlay my-multi-host-network
```

So if all the containers are running on the `my-multi-host-network` is all the traffic between the containers encrypted automatically?  In other words it's as if all the containers were running SSL and if rest is used to communicate from container A to container B, the REST request (Or requests via any other communication protocol - AMQP, etc) is encrypted?

Comment: Yes it will be encrypted. But encryption and SSL are not the same thing

Comment: Good point - I'll update the question to reflect the main concern.

Answer (score 2):

There are three networking planes in any orchestrator:

- Management plane (the "brains")
- Control plane (the "discovery")
- Data plane (the "move-packets")

The first two are encrypted by default in Swarm, you don't need to do anything special. The data plane is not encrypted by default, for performance reasons. However, you can easily encrypt it, using the `--opt encrypted` option.

If you create an encrypted network, an IPSEC tunnel will be enabled for the data-plane. So yes, all communication between containers on that network will be encrypted.